# docker-compose logging with json-file driver, where is all logging files for the container?

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

I have configured logging in a `docker-compose.yml` file like

```
services:
  some-service:
    image: some-service
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200k"
        max-file: "10"
```

but inside `/var/lib/docker/containers/$containerId/` there is only one file `json.log` with logs; are there others?

After rebuilding or restarting the container, how can I keep the previous file logs?

Answer (score 2):

There is only one file until it exceeds `max-size`. After that you will get `*-json.log.1`, `*-json.log.2`, etc.

After `docker-compose down` all container directory will be dropped. You may try another driver, like:

```
services:
  some-service:
    image: some-service
    logging:
      driver: "journald"
```

And read:

```
journalctl -b CONTAINER_NAME=workdir_some-service_1
```